# 3D Histogram from discrete data

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms

I have some (discrete) data of the type $\{x_i,y_i,z_i\}$

```
data={{4, 4, 0.6570}, {6, 4, 0.8240}, {8, 4, 0.8930}, {10, 4, 0.9330},{4,6, 0.2780}, {6,6,0.5660}, {8, 6, 0.7460}, {10, 6, 0.8320}, {4, 8,0}, {6, 8, 0.2620}, {8, 8, 0.5100}, {10, 8, 0.6100}, {4,10, 0}, {6,10, 0.04900}, {8, 10, 0.2370}, {10, 10, 0.3940}}
```

and I'm looking to make a 3D histogram out of this, with rectangles of height $z_i$ and square base located in the plane at position $x_i,y_i$.  This used to be possible using ``GeneralizedBarChart3D" but this has been replaced by RectangleChart3D and I can't make it work.

The best I can do right now is

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, Filling -> Bottom]
```

which produces something like

[image]

where the points are correctly located and at the correct height, but I want to have a rectangle (with a square base of width 1) of the correct height rather than a point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Histogram3D[Function[y, Table[{y[[1]], y[[2]]}, y[[3]]]] /@ (Function[x, {x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]*10000}] /@ data)]`

Comment: You could use ListPlot3D with a 0 interpolation order: `ListPlot3D[data, Filling -> Bottom, InterpolationOrder -> 0]`

Comment: To account for the data point {4, 4, 0.6570}, I add the point {4,4} 0.6570*10000 = 6570 times (into a temporary array). Repeat this for all points and then plot the histogram(3D) of this temporary array (containing {4,4} repeated 6570 times).

Comment: @HarshalGajjar Right... Yes I realized this soon after I posted my comment. The result is nice but since the x[[3]] component is a probability I have to now find a way to rescale the axis so that the numbers x[[3]] is >1 for plotting purposes but the vertical axis still remains between 0 and 1.

Comment: Building on @Carl's comment `ListPlot3D[data, Filling -> Bottom, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {{3, 11}, {3, 11}}, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Mesh -> None]`

Comment: @HarshalGajjar Thanks... Somehow the functionality "GeneralizedBarChart3D" was not really replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform `data` into a [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) object and use it with
[`Histogram3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html):

```
wd = WeightedData[data[[All, ;; 2]], data[[All, -1]]]; 

Histogram3D[wd, {1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Change the bin specification to `{2}`:

```
Histogram3D[wd, {2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

To show data elements with zero weight replace `0`s in the third column of data with a *small* number (say, `10^-6`):

```
wd2 = WeightedData[data[[All, ;; 2]], data[[All, -1]] /. 0 -> 10^-6]; 

Histogram3D[wd2, {1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a histogram but really a 3D bar chart as the heights don't sum to 1 or a total sample size.  But with your particular dataset where all combinations of values for each dimension (going from 4 to 10 in steps of 2) are available, one can easily use `DiscretePlot3D`:

```
DiscretePlot3D[data[[4 (i/2 - 2) + j/2 - 1, 3]], {i, 4, 10, 2}, {j, 4, 10, 2}, 
  ExtentSize -> Full, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

[image: 3D bar chart]

An alternative approach that avoids the "gymnastics" you mention is to use a sparse array:

```
data = {{4, 4, 0.6570}, {6, 4, 0.8240}, {8, 4, 0.8930}, {10, 4, 0.9330}, 
  {4, 6, 0.2780}, {6, 6, 0.5660}, {8, 6, 0.7460}, {10, 6, 0.8320}, {4, 8, 0},
  {6, 8, 0.2620}, {8, 8, 0.5100}, {10, 8, 0.6100}, {4, 10, 0}, {6, 10, 0.04900}, 
  {8, 10, 0.2370}, {10, 10, 0.3940}}
sa = SparseArray[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> #[[3]] & /@ data]
DiscretePlot3D[sa[[i, j]], {i, 4, 10, 2}, {j, 4, 10, 2}, 
  ExtentSize -> Full, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

[image: 3D bar plot alternative approach with a sparse array]

Comment: Nice.  You have to do quite a bit of gymnastics to generate the proper format for the plot...

Comment: Maybe you need more exercise. ;)