# 3D Rectangular Bar Plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to build a 3D rectangular bar plot similar to the attached image using the data table provided where each table entry is of the format (Xi,Yi,Zi) where (Xi,Yi) is the center of the the ith bar and Zi is the height. All bars should have the same size base (length*width). I have tried using Histogram3D,ListPlot3D, DiscretePlot3D but can't figure it out. Please help. Thanks!

```
data={{1/8, 1/8, 63/64}, {1/8, 3/8, 59/64}, {1/8, 5/8, 51/64}, {1/8, 7/8, 
  39/64}, {3/8, 1/8, 59/64}, {3/8, 3/8, 55/64}, {3/8, 5/8, 47/64}, {3/
  8, 7/8, 35/64}, {5/8, 1/8, 51/64}, {5/8, 3/8, 47/64}, {5/8, 5/8, 39/
  64}, {5/8, 7/8, 27/64}, {7/8, 1/8, 39/64}, {7/8, 3/8, 35/64}, {7/8, 
  5/8, 27/64}, {7/8, 7/8, 15/64}}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [3D Histogram from discrete data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224783/3d-histogram-from-discrete-data)

Comment: I hope you don't really want to include the clutter (lines or curves?) that connect the corners of the boxes.  Please see https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi?gclid=Cj0KCQiAjJOQBhCkARIsAEKMtO06J-_vdiOC2n1Adybr3-9BRMGK10YaWNG6wNdvumHVVxyX2B9FNagaAvunEALw_wcB.

Comment: Similar: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InterpretingDoubleIntegralAsAVolume/

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command for this, but you can easily create this using "Graphics3D" and "Cuboid":

```
data = {{1/8, 1/8, 63/64}, {1/8, 3/8, 59/64}, {1/8, 5/8, 51/64}, {1/8,
     7/8, 39/64}, {3/8, 1/8, 59/64}, {3/8, 3/8, 55/64}, {3/8, 5/8, 
    47/64}, {3/8, 7/8, 35/64}, {5/8, 1/8, 51/64}, {5/8, 3/8, 
    47/64}, {5/8, 5/8, 39/64}, {5/8, 7/8, 27/64}, {7/8, 1/8, 
    39/64}, {7/8, 3/8, 35/64}, {7/8, 5/8, 27/64}, {7/8, 7/8, 15/64}};
Graphics3D [
 Cuboid[{#[[1]] - 1/8, #[[2]] - 1/8, 
     0}, {#[[1]] + 1/8, #[[2]] + 1/8, #[[3]]}] & /@ data ]
```

[image]